# Docusign embedded in an iframe doesn't seem to obey cross site scripting directives

Tags: iframe, docusignapi

Just a few weeks ago, it seemed that creating a recipient view inside an iframe worked without any major complications.  But during testing today, against the demo site for development, I found that the url eventually internally resolves to something that gets blocked by my browser because "This content can't be shown in an iframe.  The publisher."

While the initial return URL return seems ok, it turns out that by the time the system resolves to account-d.docusign.com, what happens is that docusign is setting X-Frame-Origins: SAMEORIGIN, which would certainly block any iframe content.

However, while docusign says it doesn't recommend an iframe due to size issues and mobile experiences, it doesn't say that the iframe is flat out disallowed for say web applications.  In any case, setting

viewRequest.XFrameOptions = "allow_from";
viewRequest.XFrameOptionsAllowFromUrl = myHost;

Should change the X-Frame-Origins header on the url generated by the created view request, shouldn't it?

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong, or, was there a recent release by docusign that changed the behavior so that iFrames are flat out disallowed?

Comment: are you using Auth Code Grant for authentication and doing that in an iframe?
account-d.docusign.com is the URL for authentication and so I'm confused about that part.

Comment: sharing your code may help

Comment: It works fine locally, with the URL.  So my question really is, does Docusign use the X-* tags when setting up the recipient view.  If so, how do we see that, does that just use the X* tags in the header or does Docusign also create the newer content security things in its headers.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you are doing and what is the issue. you may want to ask another question or explain further, code would help. There's some confusion about the URL you mentioned that suggests to Larry and I that you're not just doing embedded signing.

Comment: I'm trying to get the basic embedded signing example to work.  The crazy part that I do not understand, that I am trying to track down, is that, the url it returns works just fine in not only another browser window on its own, but on an entirely different machine in an iframe.  It appears though, that when tracing the .har for these requests, that on the machine where it fails, there are additional content-security attributes.

Comment: do you use extra authentication features? recipients typically can sign embedded without having to authenticate . Maybe you are embedding the login using Auth Code Grant as well in the iframe. You should only embed the actual part that does the signing, not the entire app

Comment: I'm just embeddeding with the URL returned from here:

            var config = new Configuration(new ApiClient(baseDocusignAPIPath));
            config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + session.Token);
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(config);

            ViewUrl results1 = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(session.AccountId, envelopeId, viewRequest);

            string redirectUrl = results1.Url;
            return redirectUrl;

Comment: The Url works on a regular frame on another machine, in a window on a same machine, but blows up because headers on account-d docusign include content-security and x-origin options - but only in that case.  why?

Comment: I'll try to see if I have somehow embedded the login. Really, I just followed the C# docs online.  Nothing fancy.

Comment: how do you authenticate to get an access token to make API calls?

Comment: With JWT:              This appears to work across the board.

ClaimsIdentity subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
             new Claim("scope", "signature impersonation"),
             new Claim("sub", docusignUserKey)
            });
/ *stuff */

            JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
              docusignIntegrationKey,
              "account-d.docusign.com",
              expires: expire,
              claims: subject.Claims,
              signingCredentials: creds);

Comment: does it work just fine if not in an iframe? and then, can you use fiddler to tell me which URLs are being used (all the URLs that are being forwarded) ?

Comment: Hey Inbar... at the moment it actually looks like it was something a product called zscaler we were using was doing "to help us out".  Thanks!  Since your comments make an excellent check off list of what could go wrong on signing I'm leaving this answer as checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using iFrames for embedded signing works fine, but is not recommended in any circumstance. Instead, it is better to redirect the signer's browser to the embedded signing ceremony.

Using an iFrame does work, I checked it just now.

What doesn't work is to use one of DocuSign's identity servers in an iFrame (account.docusign.com and account-d.docusign.com)

Since your error is involving account-d.docusign.com, it means that something is messed up with authentication.

I think you'll need to do more testing to figure out what is happening. Check that you're using the url returned from the create recipient view API call.

Comment: It might be an internal issue.  We are using the URL.   It tested it in a different network and it was fine.

Comment: All of you please read the comment thread above by inbar as that's a really good checklist for authentication issues.